# Duplicate error on update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, str-replace

I have a table with multiple rows. Some have field `request_path` with characters like `.html.html` and others with different characters. I want to remove all `.html.html` and make them single `.html`. I am trying the below command -

```
UPDATE url_rewrite 
SET request_path = CONCAT(LEFT(request_path, CHAR_LENGTH(request_path) -10), '.html')
WHERE request_path LIKE '%.html.html';
```

But it is giving the following error -

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'test/test.html-1' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID'
```

If I deleted this entry then it started giving same error for some other values. I am not able to surpass this error. Can any one help how to fix this?

The structure of the table looks like -

[image]

Comment: Please check 'test/test.html-1' is somwhere in request_path. Also check the request_path field is set as unique or not

Comment: Yes it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have set unique key constrain in request_path column try to remove this constrain using this query and then perform the below replace query.

```
ALTER TABLE url_rewrite DROP INDEX URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID;
```

Then,

```
UPDATE url_rewrite
    SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path, '.html.html', '.html')
```

This will replace all `'.html.html'` into single `'.html'` if you want you can also use `where` condition here.

Then to reassign the constrain again use below query:

```
ALTER TABLE url_rewrite add unique index URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID (request_path (255))
```

Comment: Can you please also add how to reassign the index, as I will need that in my cms

Comment: alter table url_rewrite add unique index URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID (request_path (255)) you can use this to reassign the unique key constrain. @l

Comment: My pleasue @LAW

Answer (score 1):

By updating the table you’re attempting to create **duplicate values** because it’s violating the table’s **keys and constraints**.

You have to check the **keys** in the **url_rewrite** table and make sure that the **columns** you’re choosing as keys wan’t have duplicate values.

**Update:**

In phpmyadmin go to the url_rewrite table structure, under the columns there's an 'indexes' button, click on it you'll see the name of the index for the request_path column.

For example if that the index name is **request_path_index**, run the following query to drop that index:

```
alter table url_rewrite drop index request_path_index
```

Comment: How do you suggest to do that?

Comment: Based on your table structure, the request_path column is set to have unique values, that's why you're having the error when two records are having the same request_path value after updating. If this column's value shouldn't be unique, just remove the unique constraint and you're fine.

Comment: Can you please share how can that be done via query?

Comment: 1091 - Can't DROP 'request_path'; check that column/key exists this error came

Comment: Then in your case the index name is different than the column name. Please in phpmyadmin go to the url_rewrite table structure, under the columns there's an 'indexes' button, click on it you'll see the name of the index for the request_path column, use the name of the index instead of request_path in the query.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. The answer shared by Kunal worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.

When you do the UPDATE, the value you update becomes a duplicate to another same value. This violates the constraints of the the table and hence the error

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? I simply want to string replace .html.html to .html for all rows of a table.

Comment: Let's start with the structure of the table url_rewrite... Maybe you can edit your question and include the table structure

Comment: Updated the question, please check if it helps

Comment: You can try dropping the key to request_path column if it is ok for you.. But not recommended

Comment: Is it possible to drop the key, execute the query and then reassign the key so that the overall functionality of the cms is not effected

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @LAW Hi.. looks like you got ur answer.. I had run out for an errand, else I'd have replied!!

Comment: Thanks. And I understand, really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert/update duplicate value into  a unique property field.

Either you change the field property(remove unique property)

OR

change the request_path value before updating 
(initially check the new request path already exist. if exists, rename it. )

according to your requirement

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
UPDATE url_rewrite 
SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path , '.html.html', '.html')
WHERE request_path LIKE ('%.html.html');
```